# Storing stdout and stderr in Redis from Python Popen

Tags: python, redis

I'd like to run a command and store the results in Redis as it is run.

Although the command for the demo is **ls /etc**, in real life I'd like to use this for long running processes.

I've written out some demo code to show the idea.

Unfortunately this code when run insists on a fileno, and doesn't work, even if I simulate one.  How can I accomplish this?

```
import subprocess

import redis

class RedisFile:

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.redis = redis.StrictRedis()

        print("inited RedisFile with key:", key)

    def write(self, value):
        self.redis.append(self.key, value)


def main():
    out = RedisFile("out")
    error = RedisFile("error")

    proc = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "/etc"],
            stdout=out,
            stderr=error,
            bufsize=0
            )


main()
```

Comment: Pardon me for asking but isn't python logging better suited for this?

Comment: Good question. It's not because I want to grab the output of the subprocess as it's running, and store it in redis.  I don't want to just log things from the main process.

Answer (score -1):

you should replace sys.stdout with custom stdout.
one example like this:

`from unittest.mock import patch
with patch('sys.stdout', your_stdout),patch('sys.stderr', your_stderr):
    do_something`